# Angular 5: Prevent component reloading on parameter change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-routing

I have a route `/search` which has 2 components inside; One is a search box with results, and the other is a newsfeed that should be on every page, unrelated to the search. If I perform a search, and append parameters to the url, then results will appear below my search box, but upon re-initializing the page/component then the newsfeed is also reinitialized, having to get the same data again (This is a long running task).

How can I update the url to reflect the state change of one component, without it re-rendering another component on the page?

angularjs used to have `reloadOnSearch: false` which would solve this problem, although in a sloppy way

**Edit:** Would it be best to instead store the returned result inside a Service and then on route change, get the last result again from the service? If so, how would this be done?

**Edit:** As `cgTag` has linked to. Named outlets may be used. I am not seeing any content in place of where the outlet should be

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'view', component: ClientNewsFeedComponent, outlet: 'client-news-feed' }
];
```

search.component.html

```
<div>
  <cc-search-client-field></cc-search-client-field>
  <router-outlet name="client-news-feed"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and then browsing to the url `/search(client-news-feed:view)` the router-outlet does not render any content

**Edit:** Got it. The routing should be

```
path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, children: [
  { path: 'view', component: ClientNewsFeedComponent, outlet: 'client-news-feed' }
]
```

and url should have a /

/search/(client-news-feed:view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the `outlet` feature of a route.

https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets

This allows you to render a *secondary* route without changing the current route. You would then use the secondary route for displaying search results.

Comment: Many thanks for linking that. I have updated my question with a problem I am having with using a named router-outlet